# How many six digit numbers are there containing digits from $\{1,...,9\}$ in which no digit appears more than three times?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

The assignment doesn't have numerical answers, and I always make little errors with counting, so I'm just checking my work here.

Let $E_j$ be the event that the digit $j$ appears at most three times.

We need to find $|E_1\cap \dots \cap E_9|$

Since $E_1^C,...,E_9^C$ are mutually disjoint and all have the same size, we can say $$|E_1 \cap \dots \cap E_9|=9^6-|E_1^C \cup ... \cup E_9^C|=9^6 -9|E_1^C| $$

$E_1^C$ is the event that the six digit number has $4,5, \text{or } 6$ ones. So, by counting the number of ways we can insert the one digits and then filling in the remaining slots with digits other than $1$, we get we have $$|E_1^C|={6 \choose 4}8^2+{6\choose 5}8+{6\choose 6}=1009$$ Finally, $$|E_1\cap \dots \cap E_9|=9^6-9\cdot 1009=522,360$$

Thoughts?

Comment: This looks good, and I got the same result.  It's merciful that it is impossible to have more than one number appearing too often...this way, you don't have to worry about possible intersections.

Answer (score 1):

As lulu says in the comments, your work (and answer) appears to be correct.